# Worksheets Collection Not Set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the color of the top row of every worksheet in a workbook, however, I am getting an error:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Private Sub UpdateEnvironmentColor(MyVar As String)
    Dim CurrWrkSht As Worksheet
    
    For Each CurrWrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If MyVar = "A" Then
            CurrWrkSht.Rows(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf MyVar = "B" Then
            CurrWrkSht.Rows(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Else
            CurrWrkSht.Rows(1).Interior.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    Next CurrWrkSht
End Sub
```

The puzzling thing is that it was running fine, until I opened up a previous version of this workbook... but then I restarted everything (including my computer) to no avail.

When looking at the "CurrWrkSht" in my Locals panel, they all look fine to me (e.g. the Name property is the name I am expecting, etc.) expect for this group of properties (not sure if this matters):

[image]

My VBE is being a little finicky, but at least one time while hovering over "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" I got a tooltip mentioning this same error.

I've tried just coloring a cell, but that's not working either. Not sure what exactly the problem is. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The posted method (code) looks fine. I would only change the argument to `ByVal MyVar As String`. Could you share the code where you are calling this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

After a LOT of experimentation, and getting help from a guy with much more VBA experience than myself, it looks like the issue was protections made on the workbook. The guy who developed this had them all locked down, so when we made a call to Unprotect all the worksheets, this worked as expected.

The confusing part was that sometimes it would work, and other times it wouldn't. While troubleshooting, that led me to believe that permissions weren't the issue, but looking back now, it makes sense as the unprotect method could have been called in various scenarios thus allowing my method to go through.

Valuable lesson!